# How to use variable this way c++

Tags: c++, batch-file, variables, cmd

Im making a c++ program wherein there are multiple variables for example:
var1, var2, var3, var4;

i want to use it for a for loop like:

```
for(int x; x<=5; x++){
if(var1==1){cout << "hi";}
}
```

But instead of typing var1 i want to make it var"x" where x is equal to 1.
I remember from my batch programming days(not exact) i can use this like:

```
set x=1
echo var%x%
```

then the output will be var1.

Comment: You can't construct variable names like this in  C++. You probably want a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of `int`s, that you can access like this: `myInts[x]`.

Comment: That for loop you show won't work very well since you don't initialize `x`.

Comment: Don't add (SOLVED) and don't post "thank you" comments. Instead, upvote and accept the answer that helped you.

Comment: There is no substitute for learning C++.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to this in many script programming but unfortunately no direct support is available in C++.

Some ways around are use of arrays (if possible) or an array of pointers to actual variables.

```
int vars[5] = {...};
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
    if(var[x]==1){cout << "hi";}
}
```

or

```
int var0 = 2, var1 = 42, var2 = 7;
int *const pvars[] = {&var0, &var1, &var2};

for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    if(*(pvars[x]) == 1)
    {
        cout << "hi";
    }
}
```

or as mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41951851/how-to-use-variable-this-way-c/41951894#comment71087824_41951894)

```
int var0 = 2, var1 = 42, var2 = 7;

for(auto &var = {var0, var1, var2}) {
    if(var == 1)
    {
        cout << "hi";
    }
}
```

Comment: Since im still a student I actually forgot about arrays! Thank you for this!

Comment: Or even (in C++11) `for (int var : {var0, var1, var2}) { if (var == 1) { std::cout << "hi"; } }`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, using macros, but I really don't think it is a good idea. Why not use arrays instead? With arrays you can reference the index you want, so instead of `var1`, `var2`, `var3`, ... it will be `var[0]`, `var[1]`, `var[2]`, ... Much more C++ like, anyway.

When using arrays, I would even recommend thinking in one of the container classes C++ offers, such as [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). To have a simple array of integer variables in a vector, simply declare one such as: `std::vector<int> intVec`, to extract a specific element use the `at` function, such as `intVec.at(0)` which will extract the first element. Really use, almost any other approach, than macros.

Having said that, to do it in a macro you would need to make a macro like this:

```
#define var(x) var##x

var(1) = 2;  // resolves to var1 = 2;
```

Macros are compile time however, so using them in a loop, by passing a variable to it, will not work the way you would expect. So calling `int x = 1; var(x) = 2;` would not set `var1` to 2, but rather attempt to set `varx` to 2.

The macro solution comes with a number of disadvantages, one is making your less readable, another is making your code more error prone, and lastly, why stir away from the "C++ way"?

Comment: but he must explicitly write: `var(0), var(1), var(2)` so the loop is redundant because macro doesn't know what is (var(i)).

Comment: @Raindrop7 as also noted in the first paragraph under the example :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of command line arguments while invoking your program executable.

```
prog.exe 3 4 1 6
```

This way your program will receive 5 command line arguments, the first being the program name itself.

The code will look something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // For the above example, argc = 5
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        // make use of argv[i]
    }
}
```

This may not be exactly what you want to do, but confirms to your idea of multiple variables var1 i.e. argv[1]